# Intercept touch event in RecyclerView while ignoring EditText inside

Tags: android, kotlin

I have recyclerView with and item as seen below:

[image: list_row_item]

Now I want to be able to click anywhere on the item and editText should come into focus.
I can do that by setting `onTouchListener` on my view like this:

```
row_item.setOnTouchListener{ _, _ ->
            editText.requestFocus()
            view.background = Color.GREEN.toDrawable()
            true
        }
```

I also want to run some additional code whenever the item is clicked. Here I'm putting background color change for the sake of the example.

**The problem is that whenever I click editText itself it is getting focused, but row_item touchListener is ignored, and the background doesn't change its color.**

From my research, I've found that I should somehow intercept touch event. I thought I can do that by returning true in row_item.setOnTouchListener, but it doesn't work as you can see.

How can I intercept such touch event?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom container class and then override `onInterceptTouchEvent` method and do your stuff there, then using this custom container class as the root of the item. Look at the following code:

```
class CustomFrameLayout : FrameLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    private var mOnInterceptTouchEventListener: OnTouchListener? = null

    fun setOnInterceptTouchEventListener(onInterceptTouchEventListener: OnTouchListener) {
        this.mOnInterceptTouchEventListener = onInterceptTouchEventListener
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if(mOnInterceptTouchEventListener != null && mOnInterceptTouchEventListener?.onTouch(this, ev) == true)
            return true;
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
```

And then adding this listener to your `row_item`

```
row_item.setOnInterceptTouchEventListener(object: View.OnTouchListener {
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        editText.requestFocus()
        v?.background = Color.GREEN.toDrawable()
        return false
    }
})
```

it may not be the best answer but it works.

Comment: How can I do that?
row_item is embedded in ConstraintLayout. I tried to create CustomConstraintLayout following your example.
Then I'm changing xml ConstraintLayout to CustomConstraintLayout.
And then I'm trying to use row_item.setOnInterceptTouchEventListener but this method is not visible. So I can't use it.

Comment: What's the `row_item` data type and where is it come from?

Comment: It is a view in my CustomViewHolder: `inner class CustomViewHolder( private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)`

Comment: It should be the root of layout that you are inflating. So you should be able to cast it to `CustomConstraintLayout` and then calling `setOnInterceptTouchEventListener` method.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as possible and post some feedback here.

Comment: Did you test it? any feedback?